# Traverse a 2.5D grid

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

I'm trying to figure out how to traverse a 2.5D grid in an efficient manner.  The grid itself is 2D, but each cell in the grid has a float min/max height.  The line to traverse is defined by two 3D floating point coordinates.  I want to stop traversing the line if the range of z values between entering/exiting a grid cell doesn't overlap with the min/max height for that cell.

I'm currently using the 2D DDA algorithm to traverse through the grid cells in order(see picture), but I'm not sure how to calculate the z value when each grid cell is reached.  If I could do that, I could test the z value when entering/leaving the cell against the min/max height for the cell.

Is there a way to modify this algorithm that allows z to be calculated when each grid cell is entered?  Or is there a better traversal algorithm that would allow me to do that?

[image: grid]

Here's the current code I'm using:

```
void Grid::TraceGrid(Point3<float>& const start, Point3<float>& const end, GridCallback callback )
{
    // calculate and normalize the 2D direction vector
    Point2<float> direction=end-start;
    float length=direction.getLength( );
    direction/=length;

    // calculate delta using the grid resolution
    Point2<float> delta(m_gridresolution/fabs(direction.x), m_gridresolution/fabs(direction.y));

    // calculate the starting/ending points in the grid
    Point2<int> startGrid((int)(start.x/m_gridresolution), (int)(start.y/m_gridresolution));
    Point2<int> endGrid((int)(end.x/m_gridresolution), (int)(end.y/m_gridresolution));
    Point2<int> currentGrid=startGrid;

    // calculate the direction step in the grid based on the direction vector
    Point2<int> step(direction.x>=0?1:-1, direction.y>=0?1:-1);

    // calculate the distance to the next grid cell from the start
    Point2<float> currentDistance(((step.x>0?start.x:start.x+1)*m_gridresolution-start.x)/direction.x, ((step.y>0?start.y:start.y+1)*m_gridresolution-start.y)/direction.y);

    while(true)
    {
        // pass currentGrid to the callback
        float z = 0.0f;     // need to calculate z value somehow
        bool bstop=callback(currentGrid, z);

        // check if the callback wants to stop or the end grid cell was reached
        if(bstop||currentGrid==endGrid) break;

        // traverse to the next grid cell
        if(currentDistance.x<currentDistance.y) {
            currentDistance.x+=delta.x;
            currentGrid.x+=step.x;
        } else {
            currentDistance.y+=delta.y;
            currentGrid.y+=step.y;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a good way to do it.  Add to the start of the function:

```
float fzoffset=end.z-start.z;
Point2<float> deltaZ(fzoffset/fabs(end.x-start.x), fzoffset/fabs(end.y-start.y));
Point2<float> currentOffset((step.x>0?start.x:start.x+1)*m_gridresolution-start.x, (step.y>0?start.y:start.y+1)*m_gridresolution-start.y);
```

Inside the loop where currentDistance.x/.y are incremented, add:

```
currentOffset.x+=m_gridresolution;  //When stepping in the x axis
currentOffset.y+=m_gridresolution;  //When stepping in the y axis
```

Then to calculate z at each step:

```
z=currentOffset.x*deltaZ.x+start.z;  //When stepping in the x axis
z=currentOffset.y*deltaZ.y+start.z;  //When stepping in the y axis
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a 3D extension of the [Bresenham Line Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) would work.  You would iterate over X and independently track the error for the Y and Z components of your line segment to determine the Y and Z values for each corresponding X value.  You just stop when the accumulated error in Z reaches some critical level which would indicate it is outside of your min/max.

Comment: Unfortunately, Bresenham only finds one cell in the non-primary axis for each step of the primary axis, so it misses cells that are intersected by the line.  i.e. in the image above the first four intersected cells from the left are (2,3), (3,3), (3,4), (4,4).  Since X is the primary axis, Bresenham would skip cell (3,4)

Answer (score 0):

For each cell, you know from which cell you came from. This means you know from which side you came from. Calculating z at the intersection of the green line and a given grid line seems trivial.