# Efficient way to calculate grid quadrants a line passes through

Tags: python, r, pseudocode

I have a 2-dimmensional unit grid, and a bunch of line segments that start and end at any rational number. I need an efficient way to calculate which grid cells the line passes through. For example, the line:

From (2.1, 3.9) to (3.8, 4.8) passes through the grid cells with lower left points (2, 3), (2, 4), and (3, 4).

Is there a quick, efficient way to calculate these quadrants from the line's endpoints?

I'll be working in R, but an answer in Python or pseudocode would work too. Thanks!

Comment: You probably mean grid *cells* instead of *quadrants*.

Comment: Thanks yes you could call them cells. Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11694886/traverse-a-2-5d-grid (ignore the z part).

Comment: Hi lhf looks like a similar problem, but I don't know any c++. Any chance you could translate to R or pseudocode and post as an answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Folks who work with spatial data deal with this kind of question all the time, so it may be worth piggy-backing on their efforts. Here's a solution that uses R's **raster** package (and functions from the **sp** package on which it depends):

```
library(raster)

## Create a SpatialLines object
a <- c(2.1, 3.9) 
b <- c(3.8, 4.8)
## Method #1 -- Uses functions from the sp package.
SL <- SpatialLines(list(Lines(list(Line(rbind(a,b))), "ab")))
## Method #2 -- Uses readWKT() from the rgeos package. Easier to read.
# library(rgeos)
# string <- paste0("LINESTRING(", paste(a, b, collapse=", "), ")")
# SL <- readWKT(string)

## Create a raster object
m <- 10
n <- 10
mat <- matrix(seq_len(m*n), nrow = m, ncol = n)
r <- raster(mat, xmn = 0, xmx = n, ymn = 0, ymx = m) 

## Find which cells are intersected & get coordinates of their lower-left corners
ii <- extract(r, SL, cellnumbers=TRUE)[[1]][, "cell"]
floor(xyFromCell(r, ii))
#      x y
# [1,] 2 4
# [2,] 3 4
# [3,] 2 3

## Confirm that this is correct with a plot
image(r)
plot(as(rasterize(SL, r), "SpatialPolygons"), 
     border = "darkgrey", lwd = 2, add = TRUE)
lines(SL)
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, I didn't know extract could do this, it picks out all cells under the lines, and seems to handle zero-length lines ok too.

Comment: @mdsumner -- Good to know that, but I'm not surprised: **raster** is a phenomenally well-constructed package, ennit?

Comment: Nice answer - this line must be one of the more obtuse I've seen in recent times though `SpatialLines(list(Lines(list(Line(rbind(a,b))), "ab")))`

Comment: @thelatemail -- Is this any nicer? `library(rgeos);
string <- paste0("LINESTRING(", paste(a, b, collapse=", "), ")");
SL <- readWKT(string)`

Comment: Ha ha, someone needs to write some simpler wrappers "vector", but it is that way to allow multiple geometries within each object. Not obvious what to do to make wrappers generally useful

Comment: This works, but it doesn't scale well. If we set `m=n=100; a=c(0,0); b=c(m,n)`, the extract step takes a full half second on my (conventional) hardware. I'm trying to construct an algorithm that will repeat this operation for many iterations, and at present this step is a huge bottle neck in my program. Are there any tricks I can use to speed up this calculation for individual straight lines that connect opposite walls of a bounding box?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest some variant of [Bresenham's line algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) (or the related [Wu's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiaolin_Wu%27s_line_algorithm)). Those codes are widely used in computer graphics to draw lines and should be adaptable to your specific needs (such as non-integer endpoints).

Comment: Bresenham's algorithm does not find all cells crossed by the segment.

Comment: Hi thanks though as far as I can tell Bresenham's doesn't get every single cell the line passes through, and Wu's gets more cells than those directly passed through.

Comment: I think it's easy to modify one or both of them to work. For instance, in Brasenham's, you can mark both pixels any time you increment y (unless the line passed exactly through the corner between four cells). I'll try to work out an implementation in Python.